# Parameter list too long in initialize method

Tags: ruby

I have an initialize method for a class that looks like this:

```
def initialize(
  site:,
  name:,
  date_online: '-',
  date_offline: '-',
  date_modified: '-',
  date_tagged: '-',
  tags: []
)
  @site          = site
  @name          = name
  @date_online   = date_online
  @date_offline  = date_offline
  @date_modified = date_modified
  @date_tagged   = date_tagged
  @tags          = tags
end
```

However, RuboCop is telling me that I should:

```
Metrics/ParameterLists: Avoid parameter lists longer than 5 parameters. [7/5]
```

So, what is the best way to rectify this? It's an initializer, so all those parameters are necessary. Is the desired solution to use a hash?

```ruby
def initialize(args)
  @site          = args[:site]
  @name          = args[:name]
  @date_online   = args[:date_online]   || '-'
  @date_offline  = args[:date_offline]  || '-'
  @date_modified = args[:date_modified] || '-'
  @date_tagged   = args[:date_tagged]   || '-'
  @tags          = args[:tags]          || []
end
```

Then how should I manually handle the fact that `site` and `name` are required? I could add some code after the assignments that will throw an error if the required fields aren't present:

```ruby
raise ArgumentError unless @site && @name
```

That makes sense to me. But I assume the makers of RuboCop know what they're talking about, which leads me to suspect that there's a standard for this sort of thing.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher: Cool no problem, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An in-between solution for you might be:

```
def initialize(site:, name:, **options)
  @site          = site
  @name          = name
  @date_online   = options[:date_online]   || '-'
  @date_offline  = options[:date_offline]  || '-'
  @date_modified = options[:date_modified] || '-'
  @date_tagged   = options[:date_tagged]   || '-'
  @tags          = options[:tags]          || []
end
```

You would probably want to raise an error if an unexpected key was passed in as part of `options`.

Comment: That's great! I didn't realise you could split up parameters like that! This has helped me a lot, thank you.

Comment: Thx, but now I have `Cyclomatic complexity for initialize is too high. [7/6]` lol! Hmm, maybe have a hash with default values, then loop through that default hash, and assign to options if key doesn't exist or something.. might not improve readability though :o

Comment: @EmileVrijdags personally I take a cyclomatic complexity warning with a pinch of salt. If the code is easily understood by future maintainers, then I'll disable it for that method.